# 存在しないアドレスへの java mail api send Exception について

Tags: java

java mail api を利用してメールを送るコードを作成しました。
メールが成功的に送ることは出来ますけど、問題は存在しないメールに送る時にSendFailedExceptionを発生しないことです。

以下のように作成してエラーのテストをしてみましたが、`SendFailedException` の `catch` 
文が機能しません。
正しいコードを教えてくださったらありがたいです。

```
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mokaim@naver.com", "MR.KWON"));
        InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress(email);         
        msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);            
        msg.setSubject("This your temp", "UTF-8");            
        msg.setText("your temporary password : " + randomCount, "UTF-8");            

        Transport.send(msg);

    }catch(SendFailedException e) {
        Address[] sentAddresses = e.getValidSentAddresses();
        Address[] invalidAddresses = e.getInvalidAddresses();
        Address[] unsentAddresses = e.getValidUnsentAddresses();
        System.out.println(sentAddresses);
        System.out.println(invalidAddresses);
        System.out.println(unsentAddresses);

    } catch(AddressException ae) {            
        System.out.println("AddressException : " + ae.getMessage());           
    } catch(MessagingException me) {            
        System.out.println("MessagingException : " + me.getMessage());
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException : " + e.getMessage());         
    }

}
```

Comment: 関連質問: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/54423/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらく、存在しないメールアドレスに送信したときにエラーを検出したい、ということだろうと推察します。
残念ながら、存在しない（あるいは拒否されたとか）メールアドレスに送信した場合、送信は正常に終了するため、ここでのエラーは検出は不可能です

こういう場合は、後でエラーメールの受信という形で送信失敗を通知されます。

Comment: 解答。ありがとうございます！　そうですね。。それじゃわわいさんの言ったとりにやってみます！ありがとうございます！